# Is there a service which provides webpage screenshots and supports https to get the images

Tags: web-services, https, screenshot

I'm looking for a free web service which takes and provides screenshots of websites. This screenshots will be used as preview images for links on a website which is entirely served with the https protocol.

To avoid browser warnings like "you are loading unsecure content" the service has to provide the https protocol and should have a signed certificate.

There are lot of services which provide screenshots. See discussions: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342611 There in the list is also mentioned https://browshot.com/ which supports https but has a very restricted free version.

Comment: is it for a free and public website? If so, Browshot might be able to give you more than the 100 free screenshots per month. See last item on http://browshot.com/features: "Need more free screenshots?"